# Excel Hyperlink to XLS tries to open with MS WORD insstead of EXCEL

Tags: php, excel, xls

I have a dynamically generated excel sheet which it contains formulas using =HYPERLINK to an excel file (.xls).

When a link is clicked, it tries to open with MS Word instead of Excel, and of course prompting to convert file.

The linked XLS files are generated with PHP, I tested with an XLS that is written with MS Excel itself and it opens ok, so it looks like something wrong being done from my side when writing the XLS file.

I can confirm that MS Excel is reading some kind of headers/meta or contents to be able to guess with what app the hyperlink needs to be opened.

Anyone can shed some light if I need to change some encoding or something?

My PHPExcel code is the following

```
require_once '../../core/lib/php/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');

// If the files uses a delimiter other than a comma (e.g. a tab), then tell the reader
$objReader->setDelimiter($delimiter);
// If the files uses an encoding other than UTF-8 or ASCII, then tell the reader
//$objReader->setInputEncoding('UTF-16LE');

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($infile);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$return = $objWriter->save($outfile);
```

Comment: Have you checked what the hyperlink formula actually contains in your generated version? Is it exactly the same as in your manually created version? Normally I'd expect Excel would simply rely on the user's settings in the operating system to decide which app to use for opening a particular file (usually based on its extension). So when you say _ can confirm that MS Excel is reading some kind of headers/meta or contents_ ...what do you mean exactly? How did you confirm this, specifically?

Comment: If the PHPExcel you refer to is https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel then may I suggest updating your code to use PHPSpreadsheet instead (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). I had some problems recently with formulas added using PHPExcel and after updating to use PHPSpreadsheet the problem was fixed.

Comment: Hi all. ADyson it seems that excel is reading the contents before deciding with what to open the file. The XLS opens fine from everywhere except from a hyperlink in a cell. I set a very basic example in a new sheet and the issue occurs. As a temporary fix I am writing it into xlsx but I still would like to know why this behaviour happens AND if excel indeed reads the content of the file.

Comment: Mark, I think that is what I should do in the near future, my phpexcel is quite outdated (2 or 3 years ).... is PHPspreadsheet reverse compatabile with old phpexcel code please? I have a mega-platform that have a ton of PHPExcel writers.